# Episerver unified search check if current page ancestor has name

Tags: elasticsearch, episerver

I am trying to write a query where I want to search that if any of the ancestors has a particular name. I wrote this but doesn't work

```
query = query.Filter(i =>
(
!i.MatchTypeHierarchy(typeof(InfoPage)) |
    _contentLoader.GetAncestors(((InfoPage)i).ContentLink).MatchItem(k => k.Name.Match("foresatte"))
)
);
```

I tried this as well

```
query = query.Filter(i =>
(
!i.MatchTypeHierarchy(typeof(InfoPage)) |
    _contentLoader.GetAncestors(((InfoPage)i).ContentLink).MatchContainedCaseInsensitive(k => k.Name, "foresatte")
)
);
```

When I do this

```
(((InfoPage)i).Ancestors()
```

Then I get back ids, but I want page name to search on.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is a performance expensive approach. Try to use a custom projection that writes the ancestor name into the find registry during indexing instead.

https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/digital-experience-platform/v1.1.0-search-and-navigation/docs/customizing-default-projections

Answer (score 0):

That's the recipe:

1. Write an extension method that will provide you names of the categories to your index; something like:

```cs
public static List<string> ParentCategoryNames(this YourPageType p)
{
    var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetRequiredService<IContentLoader>();

    return contentLoader.GetAncestors(p.ContentLink).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
}
}
```

2. Add an initialization module and include the above extension method:

```cs
[ModuleDependency(typeof(FindCommerceInitializationModule))]
[UsedImplicitly]
public class FindInitializationModule : IInitializableModule
{
    public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
    {
        var client = context.Locate.Advanced.GetInstance<IClient>();

        client.Conventions.ForInstancesOf<YourPageType>().IncludeField(x => x.ParentCategoryNames());
    }

    public void Uninitialize(InitializationEngine context) { }
}
```

3. Now, you can add the property to your filter; use one of these depending on your need:

- `.InField(x => x.ParentCategoryNames())`
- `.Filter(x => x.ParentCategoryNames(), x => x.Match(term))`
- `.Filter(x => x.ParentCategoryNames(), x => x.MatchCaseInsensitive(term))`

4. Re-index data.

---

You can check if the custom data has been indexed by looking into the Search & Navigation > Overview > Explore. The JSON should contain the `ParentCategoryNames` string collection node.